# asp.net mvc 6 without IdentityUser?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-mvc

is it possible to use ASP.NET MVC 6 identity without deriving from IdentityUser?

I want to completely customize the shape and persistence of my user objects, but i still want, for example, '[Authorize]' to work.

there are lots of docs on how to get the whole default kitchen sink, but i can't find anywhere where it describes what all the moving pieces are and how to swap out the different parts. is it now an all-or-nothing deal?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Microsoft.Aspnet.Identity.EntityFramework](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/tree/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework) which is likely where your `IdentityUser` is coming from.

You can then use the above as a template for rolling your own.  Then just reference your own one, rather than the one above.